# Strange login attempt on pc

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, event-viewer

I have quite a strange situation.

A few days ago I came home to my computer being on (when it shouldn't, I did not turn it on)
Being as paranoid as I am I tried figuring out what turned on my pc and why.

Not being unfamiliar with pc's I immediately took steps to make sure it would stop. 
One of the steps I took was using event viewer to try and find any clues. What I noticed was my pc seemed to be on more than I want. With strange 'logon events' at very weird times, when I was either away or sleeping in the same room as where the pc is (this for me rules out a family member not respecting my privacy)

Below are screenshot of some of the extreme cases of what seem to be logon attempts, which made me even more paranoid.

Steps I took in the meantime:
- change my windows login code
- ran malwarebytes scan -> found nothing
- ran my nod32 antivirus full system scan -> found nothing
- ran Kaspersky antivirus -> found nothing
- ran Kaspersky rootkit removal tool -> found nothing
- checked powercfg /waketimers, there were none
- manually unplugged internet cable when computer was not in use

Does anyone know if this could be a virus or a hacker login into my pc when I'm not using it, or could it be something I'm overlooking?
More importantly I'm looking for ways I can prevent this.

For the record, I only noticed this when my pc was on last time when I turned it off before, I did not notice anything else like changed files, login attempts on any of my other account, I have 2 factor Auth for most of them.

[image]

Comment: "Does anyone know if this could be a virus or a hacker login into my PC when I'm not using it, or could it be something I'm overlooking?" - It isn't a hacker nor is it a virus.  Something you have installed or configured on your system is waking it up at or around 1900.  "More importantly I'm looking for ways I can prevent this."  - You would have to identify the hardware/software that is waking your PC.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The posted screenshot is just an example of a cluster, there are also other events at completely different times (really early in the morning, late at night). About the hardware/software waking it up, I haven't changed any hardware or settings of it in about 2-3 years and I don't recall any programs installed recently which would feature such a setting. Is it possible for either hardware or software to wake the computer up from a full shutdown? Also, do you know of a way, besides /waketimers or the event viewer to check which program it might be?

Comment: I looked at them, and without the details of each event, the screenshots really don't help.  I am not saying we need the details for hundreds of events that happen.  But the events you were viewing wouldn't have identified what was going anyways.

Comment: More than likely it is something on your system attempting to maintain itself.  However, if you are suspicious of someone actively using your computer, you could always install something to grab periodic screenshots.  One sample is www.timesnapper.com, which has a free version of their software (called "classic") that is pretty lightweight and easy to configure.

Comment: Thanks techturtle, I have since installed the software you mentioned, just to rule out that scenario. I'll report back in a couple of days if there is any news. I will continue searching for the program or setting which couldbe the culprit, but I might just  reinstall windows, just to clear everything out.

Answer (score 2):

#### Logon events that happen while you're away aren't necessarily malicious

It's perfectly normal for a system to experience logon events despite no intrusion. You don't even need any third party programs installed for this to occur; Windows itself will generate logon events.

For example, Windows comes configured out of the box with various tasks scheduled in Task Scheduler. When one of these tasks runs, it must be started in the context of a user account, even if that's something like the built-in `SYSTEM` account. This generates a logon event and is logged to the Security event log with event ID 4624.

#### How to identify unwanted logons

If you suspect unwanted use of your computer, then you need to look more closely at the events themselves. Specifically you should inspect the `Logon Type` field which distinguishes *how* the account was logged on. The possible types are:

```
Type / Description
2   Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)
3   Network (i.e. connection to shared folder on this computer from elsewhere on network)
4   Batch (i.e. scheduled task)
5   Service (Service startup)
7   Unlock (i.e. unnattended workstation with password protected screen saver)
8   NetworkCleartext (Logon with credentials sent in the clear text. Most often indicates a logon to IIS with "basic authentication") See this article for more information.
9   NewCredentials such as with RunAs or mapping a network drive with alternate credentials.  This logon type does not seem to show up in any events.  If you want to track users attempting to logon with alternate credentials see 4648.
10  RemoteInteractive (Terminal Services, Remote Desktop or Remote Assistance)
11  CachedInteractive (logon with cached domain credentials such as when logging on to a laptop when away from the network)
```

The logon types that are most suggestive of someone having gained interactive/remote access are **2**, **7**, **10**, and **11**.

For any suspicious logon events, observe the `Account Name` and  `Account Domain` fields as these will usually identify the name of the user that logged in.

If your system has already been compromised, then unwanted logons may be taking place. However, if such logons are being attempted but are failing, these can be inspected by reviewing **event ID 4625 in the Security log which indicates an attempted, but failed logon event**. The Logon Type and other fields discussed above apply to these events as well. (Note that your system must be configured to log these events before they are captured in the Event Viewer.)

#### More Information

- [Windows Security Log Event ID 4624 (An account was successfully logged on)](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624)
- [Windows Security Log Event ID 4625 (An account failed to log on)](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4625)